# How to write the daemon scripts in unix?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, daemon

Please could you tell me how to write the scripts for daemon process .

Regards,
Vedant

Comment: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/programmer/faq/

Comment: Your question is vague. Are you asking about the UNIX environment, how to use BASH, or how to daemonize a script?

Answer (score 3):

First, welcome to stackoverflow. This is probably your first question. Don't be intimidated from asking search engines and pulling your sleeves up.
I assume you are a Linux newbie. But here is a suggestion. Try reading the scripts you find under:

`/etc/init.d/`

in your machine.

If you don't understand them, get a good book about shell programming. NOT `bash`.
Bash is great as a shell, but it is slow, so some Linux distros (Debian and maybe others) don't use for init scripts.

If you are ready for a big big jump into deep water and you want an unmatched learning experience. Go to and read [Linux From Scracth](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/).

You will find lots of good stuff there. It has more than what you asked, but by reading this book, you will learn how to learn. It will make you in the a better stackoverflow community member!
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It also depends of what init system are you using. If you use systemd or upstart it's quiet different from the old sysvinit scripts, even almost every distro has their own initscripts. You should search for your distro/unixflavor documentation.